# How to parse a date column if records also have timezone in AWS Athena?

Tags: datetime, timezone, presto, amazon-athena

I'm trying to convert a date column of string type to date type in AWS Athena. This column has records that are of the format `%m-%d-%Y` or `%m-%d-%Y %H:%i:%s`

I use the below query in AWS Athena to deal with the above:

```
SELECT col1, col2,
   Coalesce(
        try(date_parse(replace("col3", '/', '-'), '%m-%d-%Y %H:%i')),
       try(date_parse(replace("col3", '/', '-'), '%m-%d-%Y')),
     try(date_parse(replace("col3", '/', '-'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'))
) AS date_col
FROM "db"."table"
```

This query works great for the above mentioned formats. But there are some records with timezone such as `3/10/2019 11:31 PM EDT`. I'm unable to parse this hence those records just show up as NULL.

I have tried `try(date_parse(replace("col3", '/', '-'), '%m-%d-%Y %H:%i %p %z'))` but that didn't work either. Is there a way to do this with `date_parse()`? I also tried something like `parse_datetime("col3", 'MM/DD/YYYY' 'HH:mm' 'P' 'Z')` but that didnt work either. Is there another workaround for this or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

You can parse it with the following pattern for the [`parse_datetime`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html?highlight=parse_datetime#parse_datetime) function:
`MM/dd/YYYY hh:mm a z`. The pattern format is based on [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html).

For example:

```sql
WITH t(x) AS (VALUES '3/10/2019 11:31 PM EDT')
SELECT parse_datetime(x, 'MM/dd/YYYY hh:mm a z') 
FROM t
```

produces:

```
                  _col0
------------------------------------------
 2019-03-10 23:31:00.000 America/New_York
```

Comment: I tried this and it failed with this error `NOT_SUPPORTED: Unsupported Hive type: timestamp with time zone.`

Comment: If you're trying to insert the result into another table, you'll need to convert it to another type that's supported (e.g., TIMESTAMP). Note that Athena is based on a very old version of Presto from more than 3 years ago and some features in the latest versions of Presto may not be present there.

Comment: I tried to do ```Coalesce( try(date_parse(replace("col3", '/', '-'), '%m-%d-%Y %H:%i')),         try(CAST(parse_datetime(replace("col3", '/', '-'),'MM/dd/YYYY hh:mm a z') AS TIMESTAMP))```, but the rows with the timezone were just all converted to NULLS